What does καὶ περισσὸν ἔχωσιν (Jn 10:10) imply about the life Jesus came to give? Does He imply both 'life' eternal and temporal in varying degrees?
John 10:10b:
I have come that they may have Life, and may have it in abundance (Weymouth NT).

What does καὶ περισσὸν ἔχωσιν (Jn 10:10) imply about the life Jesus came to give? Does He imply both 'life' eternal and temporal in varying degrees?
John 10:10b: (Weymouth NT)

I have come that they may have Life, and may have it in abundance.
.

In John 10:10, the phrase καὶ περισσὸν ἔχωσιν, meaning “and have it in abundance,” suggests a life marked by fullness and richness, encompassing both eternal and earthly dimensions. However, it carries a deeper truth: this promise is not unconditional.
Jesus makes clear that the abundant life is offered to those who come to Him, follow Him, and embrace His message. Beginning His ministry by proclaiming, “Repent (return to God) and believe in the gospel, for the kingdom of Heaven is near” (Mark 1:15),
Jesus speaks as the Savior who came to “His own people” (Old Covenant) and to the lost of the world (New Covenant). In this context, the invitation to an abundant life requires a commitment to Jesus as the Shepherd—listening to His voice and living out His words. It all begins with a turn toward God in faith and repentance.
Temporal Life and Divine Provision
In the Old Testament, God promised Israel abundant blessings: a land flowing with “milk and honey,” fruitful harvests, freedom from sickness and oppression, and protection from enemies.
In a similar way, Jesus extends both spiritual and physical provision, offering peace, strength, and relief from burdens to those who accept Him as Lord and Shepherd. He reassures His followers, “Do not worry about your life, what you will eat or drink; or about your body, what you will wear… Look at the birds of the air; they do not sow or reap or store away in barns, and yet your heavenly Father feeds them. Are you not much more valuable than they?” (Matthew 6:25-26). Jesus further reminds us, “Your Father knows what you need before you ask him” (Matthew 6:8).
This “life in abundance” reflects the same care and sustenance God provided to Israel. Yet, like the Israelites, who were called to be faithful by keeping His commandments and precepts, Jesus’ “sheep” are likewise called to live in faithful obedience. Just as Israel depended on God during their wilderness journey, believers are invited to rely on Jesus in faith, receiving His provision as they follow Him.
Eternal Life and Spiritual Fullness
In verse 10, Jesus says, He came to give 'life and may have it in abundantly.'
The phrase καὶ περισσὸν ἔχωσιν also implies that a life of richness overflows from the eternal life found in Christ. This abundant life includes a secure, everlasting relationship with God, bringing profound joy, peace, and purpose. However, this fullness of life is reserved for those who are “born again” and who actively seek and follow Jesus’ teachings, not for those who remain indifferent to His call.
Psalm 23 captures the essence of Jesus’ promise of abundant life. David’s declaration, “The Lord is my shepherd; I shall not want,” reflects a life marked by God’s provision, guidance, and overflowing peace.
The psalm’s imagery of green pastures and a prepared table presents a picture of God’s sustenance and care for those who, like David, place their trust in Him and walk in His ways.
Conclusion
The “life in abundance” Jesus offers in John 10:10 is a rich, comprehensive promise—but it is not given unconditionally. It is offered to those who turn to Jesus, repent, and follow Him as disciples. For these followers, the abundant life involves both temporal and eternal blessings, reflecting God’s provision for physical needs, freedom from spiritual burdens, and the promise of eternal life. Psalm 23 aptly captures this promise, showing the depth of fulfillment found in living under the care of the Good Shepherd.
Yet, as Solomon observed in Ecclesiastes 1:2, all temporal abundance, success, riches, and fame—if not rooted in God—are ultimately ‘vanity of vanities, all is vanity.'
Believers are reminded to heed Solomon’s wisdom: ‘Fear God and keep his commandments, for this is the duty of all mankind. For God will bring every deed into judgment…whether it is good or evil’ (Ecclesiastes 12:13-14).
This calls each of us to seek the true abundance found in a life committed to God through Christ, the only source of lasting fulfillment and eternal life.
Finally, the “life in abundance” Jesus offers in John 10:10 is a genuine promise—not a prosperity scheme—extended to His sheep (believers) who hear, know, and faithfully follow their Shepherd.
Sola Scriptura!   Sola fide!    Solus Christus!    Sola Gratia!     Soli Deo Gloria!

The Phrase
The operative phrase in John 10:10 highlighted by the OP is:

καὶ περισσὸν ἔχωσιν = and abundantly have [it, ie, life, ζωὴν]

"life, ζωὴν"
We should observe that Greek has two words for "life" which are:

ζωή (zoe) = is the divine life that imparts life to all else in which the Christian may share
βίος (bios) = is the always earthly life or livelihood

In John's gospel, we find the phrase "eternal life" (ζωὴν αἰώνιον) far more often than anywhere else in the NT.  Further, ζωή always refers to life from/imparted by God in which the saved Christian can share.  This is best summarized in the famous statement in 1 John 5:11, 12 -

And this is that testimony: God has given us eternal life, and this
life is in His Son. Whoever has the Son has life; whoever does not
have the Son of God does not have life.

Now, back to the Gospel of John.  One of the great teachings of the John is that this eternal life starts in the present earthly life:

John 5:24 - Truly, truly, I tell you, whoever hears My word and
believes Him who sent Me has eternal life and will not come under
judgment. Indeed, he has crossed over from death to life.

Even the opening prologue emphasizes this as one of the major themes of John's gospel:

John 1:4 - In Him was life, and that life was the light of men. (see also John 5:26)
John 8:12 - Once again, Jesus spoke to the people and said, “I am the
light of the world. Whoever follows Me will never walk in the
darkness, but will have the light of life.”

When Jesus discussed spiritual matters with the Samaritan woman at Jacob's well, He told her something similar:

John 4:14 - but whoever may drink of the water that I will give him
will never thirst, to the age. Instead, the water that I will give to
him will become in him a spring of water, welling up into eternal
life."

Jesus emphasized this again in His sermon on the bread of life in John 6 -

John 6:47 - Truly, truly, I tell you, he who believes has eternal
life. [Note that ἔχει = "has" is present indicative active.]

The same idea is repeated in John 10:28 -

I give them eternal life, and they will never perish. No one can
snatch them out of My hand. [The verb δίδωμι = "give" is present
indicative active.]

John 10:10
In this context, Jesus is saying something very significant in John 10:10 - Jesus' disciples/saved Christian enjoy eternal life in the present life.  That is, the present "grind" of earthly life is made vastly better with the confident knowledge that we presently have eternal life, and this life is in the Son (1 John 5:11, 12).
That is, this earthly life is limited and we all die.  By contrast, Jesus came to give eternal life; thus our present life can be abundant beyond anything we could imagine and limitless in both extent and quality.
Gill expresses it thus:

I am come that they might have life; that the sheep might have life,
or the elect of God might have life, both spiritual and eternal; who,
as the rest of mankind, are by nature dead in trespasses and sins, and
liable in themselves to an eternal death: Christ came into this world
in human nature, to give his flesh, his body, his whole human nature,
soul and body, for the life of these persons, or that they might live
spiritually here, and eternally hereafter;


To combine the present life with eternal life is classic in Jesus' statements quoted in the Gospel of John.
John 10:10 ... ἵνα ζωὴν ἔχωσιν ⸋καὶ ⸀περισσὸν ἔχωσιν ... are present active subjunctives "that they may have life and have it abundantly." Thus, the start is during this life.  The next verse extends this to eternal life:

I am the good shepherd. The good shepherd lays down his life for the sheep.
(John 10:11, ESV)

Christ did not need to die for us to have our present life, but for our eternal life.  Also see the following verses.
John 3:16 ... ἔχῃ ζωὴν αἰώνιον. is present active subjunctive "have eternal life."
John 3:36 ... ἔχει ζωὴν αἰώνιον ... is present active indicative "has eternal life."
John 5:24 ... ἔχει ζωὴν αἰώνιον ... is present active indicative "has eternal life."
John 6:47 ... ἔχει ζωὴν αἰώνιον ... is present active indicative "has eternal life."
John 6:54 ... ἔχει ζωὴν αἰώνιον ... is present active indicative "has eternal life."
Then is Jesus' statement to Martha:

Jesus said to her, “I am the resurrection and the life. Whoever believes in me, though he die, yet shall he live, and everyone who lives and believes in me shall never die. Do you believe this?”
(Johnn 11:25–26, ESV)


In John 10:10, the phrase καὶ περισσὸν ἔχωσιν ("and have it abundantly") suggests that Jesus’s purpose includes offering a life that transcends mere survival or physical existence, encompassing both eternal and temporal aspects. The Greek term περισσὸν (perisson) implies not only “abundance” but also “overflow,” indicating a life that is enhanced beyond ordinary existence.
The connection to Hebrews 7:16, "Who is made, not after the law of a carnal commandment, but after the power of an endless life," introduces a significant dimension when considering the term ἀκαταλύτου (akatalytou), meaning “endless” or “indestructible.” Here, ἀκαταλύτου provides a key to understanding the nature of the life Jesus offers. Unlike the temporary, perishable life bound by the physical laws (and, by extension, the "carnal commandment"), ἀκαταλύτου implies a life that is enduring and not subject to decay.
The word ἀκαταλύτου derives from καταλύω, meaning “to dissolve” or “to destroy.” Thus, ἀκαταλύτου can also carry the sense of “indissoluble” or “perpetual,” giving the life Jesus offers a dual aspect: it is temporal in the sense of transforming current life experiences with joy, purpose, and fullness, but it is also eternal, unbounded by the usual limitations of mortality.
This range of meanings allows us to interpret καὶ περισσὸν ἔχωσιν in John 10:10 as indicating not just the offer of eternal life in the eschatological sense, but also an enriched, empowered existence here and now. Jesus, then, brings a life empowered by the ἀκαταλύτου quality—an endless life that invigorates earthly existence and prepares for the eternal. Thus, περισσὸν implies a life that exceeds natural limitations, embracing both a superabundant present life and the unending life to come, connected by the indestructible, divine power shared through Christ.

The excess He speaks about is the same excess and unexpected intensity of love and peace of which also Paul speaks: "What no eye has seen, nor ear heard, nor the heart of man imagined, what God has prepared for those who love him" (1 Cor. 2:9).
Take a  analogy:
One thing is if you become a tennis player and train yourself. Another thing is if you play your first competition. Still another thrill is if you win your first match in a competition. Furthermore, what if you win the very competition, what a joy will be there in your heart! Now, go further and what if you are allowed at pro-tour to play a challenger or futures? What if you win either of the two and are allowed henceforth to the ATP tour! What if you win your first 100 points ATP tournament? What if 500 points ATP tournament? What if even 1000 points ATP? And what if, yes, what if you compete and even win Grand Slam tournaments like French Open, US Open or Australian Open? And eventually, what if you shine on the Wimbledon grass and win this pearl of all tennis tournaments! What a joy will overflow you! But I am speaking about an earthly, transient joy, that for angels and saints is like a cow manure in comparison with the intransient and ever increasing joy they experience in Heavens.
